# Sorting a dynamic range based on cell value

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, range

I want to sort these totals by client code (Row B) only for those under 200$. My code is not working, where is my mistake? (keep in mind the number of rows change all the time but columns stay the same)

[image: Excel sheet]

```
Sub SortD()    
    Dim TotalRows As Long
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range

    TotalRows = Application.CountA(Range("F:F"))

    For i = 3 To TotalRows
        If Cells(i, 6).Value >= 200 Then

           Set rng1 = Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(i - 1, 9))
           Set rng2 = Range(Cells(3, 2), Cells(i - 1, 2))

            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next i

    Application.Goto rng1
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=rng2, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
        .SetRange rng1
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by your code isn't working?  Does it error out, if so at what line?  If it isn't erroring out what is it doing?  Also, what do you mean only when the value is greater than 200?  If row 1 is 210, row 2 is 100 and row 3 is 50 does that mean that only row 3 and row 2 should switch?

Comment: Thank you for the speedy response! My macro is not erroring out. It is just not doing anything. The totals will always be sorted in ascending order, and the last ones will be above 200$ (not in my image, but you get the idea) I want to sort all client codes for totals under 200$. The last 3-5 rows usually will be above 200$ depending on the time.

Comment: The obvious mistake is Exit Sub. You have to use **Exit For**.

Comment: Voting to close this question as it is due to a *simple typographical error*

Comment: Thank you all for your input on this question. I'm a beginner at VBA, still learning the basics...